# Customize acronyms usage of first use

Tags: macros, acronyms

So I have a list of acronyms defined with the glossaries package, like such:

```
\newacronym{mac}{MAC}{Medium Access Control}
```

but also some of these:

```
\newcommand{\mk}{Master Key}
```

because the latter one shall not be abbreviated but I don't want to type it all the time (can that be achieved with the glossaries package? Would be neat).

What I'm trying to achieve is, that both usecases print the word on first usage in italic. The acronyms (`\newacronym`) are then supposed to print the abbreviation (as it is per default) and the other like they are.

Any suggestions on how to do that in the glossaries package? And something more elegant for the other macros then toggles for each one?

Edit:
I ended up defining meta commands

```
\newcommand*{\firstit}[3][]{\it{#3#1}\expandafter\gdef\csname#2\endcsname{#3}}

\newcommand*{\firstitacr}[4][]{{\it{#4#1} (#3)}\expandafter\gdef\csname#2\endcsname{#3}}
```

which are used to define the acronyms and proper names

```
\newcommand*{\mk}[1]{\firstit[#1]{mk}{Master Key}}

\newcommand*{\mac}[1]{\firstitacr[#1]{mac}{MAC}{Medium Access Control}}
```

these can then be used like this:

```
First usage of proper name: \mk{}
Second usage: \mk{}

First usage of acronym: \mac{}
Second usage: \mac{}
```

which would be rendered to something like this

> First usage of proper name: *Master Key*
>   Second usage: Master Key
>
> First usage of acronym: *Medium Access Control* (MAC)
>   Second usage: MAC

I'm pretty sure, that there is a more elegant solution, but this works for me.

Comment: Why use `glossaries` for the second one? Just use `\newcommand\mk{\textit{Master Key}\gdef\mk{Master Key}}` and it will be italic for the first time and every following usage will just print it in the current font.

Comment: Thanks @Skillmon thats a neat solution I haven't thought of!

Comment: But that only works very limited.  
1. I can't simply append an 's' that is italic if and only if the word is, or is there a command to read out the font-style of the previous word?  
2. I still don't have a solution to make the first use of `\gls` italic, and I still want to use `\glsreset`

Any ideas?

Comment: Go read the manual of `glossaries`, it's the same what I'd do. You can change the definition of `\mk` to `\newcommand\mkFormatting[1]{\textit{#1}\gdef\mkFormatting#1{#1}}\newcommand\mk[1][]{\mkFormatting{Master Key#1}}`. After that you can use `\mk[s]` to get "Master Keys" in the correct formatting.

Comment: I can't really grasp what happens there, can you explain that?

Comment: Yes. We define two commands, one responsible for the formatting (`\mkFormatting`) that typesets its argument as `\textit` and redefines itself to typeset its argument as is (we use the TeX syntax of `\gdef` to make this redefinition global). `\mk` is a macro with an optional argument. It passes "Master Key" and the optional argument (which by default is empty) on to `\mkFormatting`. Enough explanation?

Comment: Just noticed I made a mistake up there. Should be: `\newcommand\mkFormatting[1]{\textit{#1}\gdef\mkFormatting##1{##1}}` the doubled hashtags are necessary. That happens if you type without thinking:)

Comment: What do the ## do?

Comment: Inside of a `\newcommand` a `#1` gets evaluated as the first argument. If you want to define something inside of a definition, you have to escape the `#` with another one. `##1` is the first argument of a definition inside of a definition (I hope this is understandable).